# Use 2 instance of the component on the page in Angular

Tags: angular

I have some component for the custom checkbox that I want to use in the different places on the web-site (to not repeat styles, markup, etc.
But the problem is - I'm getting the same instance of this component. So I'm changing the "checked" state of the first checkbox component when I'm clicking on the first or second checkbox (doesn't matter).
I need that these two "checkbox" component will be two different instances and have the different properties. Is it possible for the Angular2+?

Checkbox component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox',
  template: `
    <label for="checkbox" [class.active]="isChecked">
      <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" (change)="change(checkbox.checked)" #checkbox>
    </label>
  `,
  styles: [`
    label {
      display: block;
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
      background: #32353a no-repeat center;
      border: 1px solid #64676c;
      transition: background-color .5s;
    }
    label:hover {
      background-color: #45494e;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .active {
      background-image: url(../assets/img/checked.png);
    }
    input {display: none;}
  `]
})

export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public isChecked: boolean;
  @Output() public onChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isChecked = !!this.isChecked;
  }

  public change(value: boolean): void {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    this.onChange.emit(this.isChecked);
  }
}
```

SettingsComponent's html where I'm using this CheckboxComponent:

```
<checkbox [isChecked]="true" (onChange)="change('invert', $event)"></checkbox>
<checkbox [isChecked]="true" (onChange)="change('touchscreen', $event)"></checkbox>
```

Like I said in the comments, I have the SharedModule that importing and exporting the CheckboxComponent

SharedModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CheckboxComponent } from './checkbox/checkbox.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CheckboxComponent ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [ CheckboxComponent ],
  providers: [ URLWatcherService ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

This is the SettingsControlComponent that imports by the SettingsModule

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'settings-controls',
  templateUrl: './settings-controls.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './settings-controls.component.css', '../settings-common/settings-common.css' ]
})

export class SettingsControlsComponent {
  @Output() public onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public change(controlName: string, value: any): void {
    let newValue = {};
    newValue[controlName] = value;
    this.onChange.emit(newValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you're not getting the same instance. Multiple components of the same type are by definition individual instances. Most likely, you're handling the output(s) in the calling component in such a way that the a single variable is being changed. Show us the calling logic and template.

Comment: Just added above

Comment: Please show the `SettingsComponent` TS logic, where you are defining `change()`.

Comment: Added at the end of the text

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, to make a component "sharable", you need to declare it in a module and export it :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [/* required imports */],
  declarations: [CheckboxComponent],
  exports: [CheckboxComponent],
  providers: [/* your providers */]
})
```

Now, when you need to use your component in another module, all you have to do is import this module and use your component selector in your HTML.

What I do is, all of those shared components are declared in a module named `SharedModule`, that I use in all my application.

Comment: I doubt if this is the problem.

Comment: It is not working for me. I have the SharedModule that imports and exports CheckboxComponent (and others). I'm importing SharedModule in the module where I'm using CheckboxComponent.

Comment: And what is your problem then ?

Comment: Oh I get it, sorry I misread your post. You problem is located at `this.onChange.emit(this.isChecked);`, I think it's because it has the same name so Angular thinks it's only one event.

Comment: Removed the @Output property. Still the same.